# What was Nietzsche saying in Chapter 2 of Thus Spake Zarathustra?

Tags: nietzsche

Chapter 2 of Thus Spake Zarathustra has this passage:

"When Zarathustra heard the wise man thus speak, he laughed in his heart: for thereby had a light dawned upon him. And thus spake he to his heart..."

It was copied from this [link](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/n/nietzsche/friedrich/n67a/chapter2.html).

Previous to this passage in Chapter 2 I thought Zarathustra was the wise man speaking.  Was he the wise man or was Zarathustra listening to a different wise man?

Comment: The sayings of the wise man are preceded by "To him went Zarathustra, and sat among the youths before his chair. And thus spake the wise man:...". Zarathustra could not have sat among the youths before a chair *and* spoke from that same chair.

Comment: To add to the above, the wise man is, like the hunchback and the ugliest man, an archetype that Nietzsche challenges with his new archetype of Zarathustra. Here Nietzsche is parodying the archetype of the traditional wise person.